# Catch Http Response Errors in Rxjs Epic using Fetch

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, rxjs, fetch, observable

In React, I need to examine the HTTP error response objects (e.g. a 400 bad request has a sub-object with each failed validation message) but the normal means of using catchError doesn't allow this, because the Error is a different object and the error is thrown before it gets to the map((response) so it also can't be handled in the same place as the normal response.  So it seems you need to access the http error right at the start but the syntax is not very obvious.  You can see some of my attempts commented in the code.  I'm now sure how to intercept an error at that stage but then have the map((response) line continue after it properly.  Anyone have an idea?  Many thanks.

````
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(DataActionEnum.Fetch_Data),
    withLatestFrom(state$),
    mergeMap(([action, state]: [IFetchDataAction, IApplicationState]) => {
      return DataAPIClient.get<any>(`Position?assets=${action.asset}`).pipe(
        //catchError((err: any, caught: any) => {
        //  if (err.code === 400) {
        //    return of(FetchDataFailureAction("x"), sendToast("Test", ToastType.Error));
        //  }
        //}),
        // map((res: any) => {
        //   if (res.ok) return res.json();
        //   const x = res.status;
        //   throw res;
        // }),
        map((response) => {
          if (response.status === 400) {
            const error = response.data;
            return of(FetchDataFailureAction(error), sendToast(error, ToastType.Error));
          }
          const data = response.data;
          return FetchDataSuccessAction(data);
        }),
        catchError((x: any) => {
          const error = "API Issue - " + x.message;
          return of(FetchDataFailureAction(x.message), sendToast(error, ToastType.Error));
        })
      );
    })
  );```
````

Answer (score 0):

Consider spending some time here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch

I think your use-case is similar to "Example 2: Catching rejected promise"

EDIT:

I think you can handle this by chaining multiple `pipe`s:

```
    mergeMap(([action, state]: [IFetchDataAction, IApplicationState]) => {
      return DataAPIClient.get<any>(`Position?assets=${action.asset}`)
         .pipe(
            map((response) => {
              if (response.status === 400) {
                const error = response.data;
                return of(FetchDataFailureAction(error), sendToast(error, ToastType.Error));
            }
            const data = response.data;
            return FetchDataSuccessAction(data);
        })
)
         .pipe(
            catchError((x: any) => {
              const error = "API Issue - " + x.message;
              return of(FetchDataFailureAction(x.message), sendToast(error, ToastType.Error));
            })
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the attempt but this gives the same result as having it in one pipe.  The if (response.status === 400) { line never gets run because it errors before it gets there.  That's why I need to catch the HTTP error before it gets to the mapping else it's too late. This version ends up with the value of x in catchError being the same as before - it has  a single text line for the error not any of the HTTP response error object that is needed.

Comment: I went through the link provided and it doesn't contain any clues - the examples are very simple ones that I already followed, it doesn't show you how to catch an error at the very start but then continue with the mapping after that if there isn't an error.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. Can you try doing what I did but reversing the 2 pipes? So you're using `cathError` before `map`?